# Access PNG Metadata

Tags: png, metadata, image-formats

How can I access/remove PNG metadata?

I'm looking for a Mac application or a PHP snippet.

Comment: Filesystem metadata? Exif tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`Smush_it`](http://www.imgopt.com/faq.php) image optimizer + API.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the link; this isn't the solution I'm looking for, but it seems real helpful in future web builds.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to post a Windows software, but if you don't find anything good for MAC, there's [TweakPNG](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/), which is by far the best PNG disassembler I've seen.

Comment: Worked for me! [win 7]

Answer (score 4):

[PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) can remove metadata as well as optimize/recompress the bitmap images.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Any clue as to how I compile it in Terminal?

Comment: It's available in MacPorts if you have that installed, with "port install pngcrush".  Otherwise you will need to follow the build instructions and may need the apple developer packages for headers etc.

Answer (score 2):

[exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool) is a Perl command-line application and library that has the ability to write PNG metadata.  It is multi-platform, and even has an OS X installer version.

Answer (score 1):

A search for png on [iUseThis](http://osx.iusethis.com/search?q=png) yields a long list of apps for trimming pngs.

I have [ImageOptim](http://osx.iusethis.com/app/imageoptim) installed, but I cannot remember if that one really was the best of them all. I did try out a few.

Answer (score 0):

My [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993678/png-optimisation-tools/2000540#2000540) gives a short Python script that removes all non-critical chunks.  You'll need to download PyPNG, but that's just one Python file.