# Creating an image with PHP - Large file size

Tags: php, image-processing, png, image-resizing, imagecreatefrompng

### The Problem

I'm trying to resize a 260x310px PNG to 120x120px while also retaining the transparency and centring the image. I have included the function i'm using below, it works fine in terms of the appearance of the image, however the images created are alot bigger. Infact all the images appear to be 128kb (there are thousands I haven't looked at all of them) and a directory of 50,000 of these images is 1gb bigger despite the images being over half the size (in pixels).

I imagine this is because PHP isn't doing any optimisation in the way that say Photoshop might. Is there anything I can do to optimise the image in PHP?

### The Code

This is my Code:

```
if ($handle = opendir($mydir_path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strpos($entry, '.png'))
        {
            resize($mydir_path.$entry);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

function resize($img_loc)
{
    $mini_loc = str_replace('megapack', 'handheld_megapack', $img_loc);

    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(310, 310);
    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 255, 255, 255, 127));
    imagealphablending($canvas, false);
    imagesavealpha($canvas, true);

    $img = imagecreatefrompng($img_loc);
    imagecopy($canvas, $img, 25, 0, 0, 0, 260, 310);

    $resizedImg = imagecreatetruecolor('120', '120');
    imagefill($resizedImg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($resizedImg, 255, 255, 255, 127));
    imagealphablending($resizedImg, false);
    imagesavealpha($resizedImg, true);

    imagecopyresampled($resizedImg, $canvas, 0, 0, 0, 0, '120', '120', '310', '310');

    $dirname = dirname($mini_loc);

    imagepng($resizedImg, $mini_loc, '0');

    chmod($mini_loc, 0666);

    return $mini_loc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be possible to optimize the file with PHP, it will be easiest to run it through a program like [pngcrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush).

With GD you could try using the third parameter of [imagepng](http://php.net/imagepng) "quality" and set it to 9 (you have it set to 0 = no compression) but you will gain much more with a specialized PNG optimizer.

Also check this question: [PNG optimisation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993678/png-optimisation-tools)

Comment: I have been looking at pngcrush and it may be the solution. I'll give you a +1 but hopefully someone will give some insight into optimising PHP generated images :)

Comment: Thanks, I have extended my answer a little.

Comment: Ah damnit, that seems so obvious! That has greatly reduced the filesize to just 20kb and no obvious loss of quality.

Comment: Also after using pngcrush on the image with 9 optimisation less than 1kb was saved afterwards, so it seems 9 optimisation is enough

Comment: Yep made a 3gb dir 1gb with no obvious loss of quality. The answer was so obvious that i'm a little embarrassed!