# base64_encode($image) Image size compression - PHP

Tags: php, image, optimization, png, php-gd

I have couple of png transparent layer to merge. All images combine and generate an image. But the image has more than 1 MB in size. I can't push all the code here but my idea is

1. Add multiple PNG transparent layers
2. Convert into base64 encode string and return to the browser
3. Show the image

Here is my PHP [FIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b8xg-ivw7) to check the code from line no. `77` to `81`. You can see my complete code. I need to compress the image size of base64 encoded image. Is there any way to how to do that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can avoid this complicated step by activating your Web Server compression module

Comment: I tried that too, not get much effective. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993678/png-optimisation-tools This question has some points. But I am not storing image on the server, I am just merging it and reverting it back to the browser.

Comment: are you using Apache web server ?

Comment: If `imagepng($out, null, 9)` did not help, there is nothing more you can do. Filters may help a bit, but you increase image size by ~30% encoding it in base64 anyway.

Comment: @HalayemAnis yes I am using Apache web server.